# How can I identify the first occurrence of a repeating event in Calendar

Tags: calendar

Before Sierra Calendar and after "defaults write com.apple.iCal IncludeDebugMenu 1" we could locate the first event of a repeating event in our calendar. This was extremely useful for deleting all linked events from without having to hunt them down one by one. This would be required if one of the events became disassociated from the rest of the repeating events because a change had been made to it, like time of day.

Has anyone figured out how to replace this removed "feature" - the debug menu?

Comment: Why not just delete the next (or previous) occurrence?  It should prompt you to delete the rest in the series.

Comment: Thank you. The primary reason to find the original is to delete all recurring events that were created from that original Master event - past and future - without having to hunt for them. Calendar only deletes the highlighted event and "Future Events" leaving orphaned events from earlier dates. Thus the need to find the Master. As stated, this was a feature in the debug menu up until Sierra. It was called, "Show Master Event", and I used it often when editing recurring events.

Comment: Yes but I still don't understand why you need to delete *every single one of them*.  It takes up virtually no space at all; a calendar event is a database entry with a bit of data.  It won't drain space or compute resources, so why spend more time hunting for the original?  I'm sorry, I don't think you can enable the debug menu anymore.

Comment: I don't know,,, because I want to and I have OCD..... it bothers me when I do a search for something and multiple versions of the event title clutter up the drop down menu; I don't like paying to sync more data to my iDevices than I need to; probably more reasons but I can't remember them right now. Anyhow, I did find the command that enables the Debug menu. As far as I know it's not been documented on High Sierra until now.

Answer (score 2):

One out-of-the-box method is to drag the event to the desktop, creating a .ics file. When you have a QuickLook of the .ics file by pressing the space bar, a preview of the recurring event will come up with the event's start date in the title bar.
Works with Big Sur.[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK! I used the old show debug menu command from Mavericks and it works in High Sierra - Catalina! Looks like this is the first time this info has been published for High Sierra, hope folks find it useful. Only trouble is "Show Master Event" is no longer in the menu.

defaults write com.apple.iCal CDB 1

Answer (score 1):

Pull up the calendar on your Mac, search for the title of the event, find the first occurrence, and delete that.  It will ask if you want to delete the whole series.